# Multiline string in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a multiline string as follows"

```
var str1 = document.getElementById('text1');
var str2 = document.getElementById('text2');
var str = str1.value + "\n" + str2.value;
```

I now want to add this string to a div that I create in a popup window as follows:

```
myWindow=window.open('','Full_text','width=600,height=600');
myWindow.document.write('<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; width: 580px; top: 30px; height: 550px; overflow: auto;">' + str + '</div>');
```

But I do not get a multiline string in the div. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Line breaks are not rendered in HTML without this CSS property:

```
white-space: pre;
```

You can try to replace `str` to this:

```
var str = str1.value + "<br/>\n" + str2.value;
```

Answer (score 4):

Line break is not presented when rendering in HTML, if you just need a line break, please use `<br>` instead of `\n` If you want to keep white spaces, tabs, you should try to wrap the string with a `<pre>string goes here.</pre>` tag.